# Parallel::ForkManager gives - child process STDIN is not a real system Error

Tags: perl, eval, stdin, file-descriptor, openssh

I have a script which does ssh to number if servers(`@hosts`) stored in an array and executes certain commands on those hosts.

```
...
use Net::OpenSSH;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
 
#these hosts are the IP addresses
my @hosts = ("host1", "host2", "host3", "host4", "host5"); 

my $ssh;
my $command = "perl -e "print \"Hello..\"";

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
 
LOOP:
foreach my $n (@hosts) {
  my $pid = $pm->start and next LOOP;
 
  #doing ssh to the host and running the command
  #lets say here I am executing simple Perl command 
  $ssh = Connect($n, "user", "passwd");
  $ssh->capture($command);
 
  $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
undef $ssh;

sub Connect {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd ) = @_;
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user=>$user, password=>$passwd);
    $ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: " . $ssh->error;
    return $ssh;
}
...
```

When I execute this script, I am getting below error which is like nightmare to me.

```
child process STDIN is not a real system file handle at (eval 2) line 145
```

I don't why this error occurs. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Am I missing something in `$pm->finish` or do I need to add `$pm->run_on_finish(..)` ?

Comment: That message is not from P::FM, and P::FM doesn't touch STDIN

Comment: Re "*Do I need to add `$pm->run_on_finish(..)`*", No, not unless you want to do something in the parent when a child completes.

Comment: Re "*Am I missing something in `$pm->finish`*", No.

Comment: `open(my $fh, '<', \$buf)` is an example of a handle with no underlying system file handle.

Comment: @ikegami: No, I don't want to do anything in the parent. The `$command` will create some logs in remote machine that's it.

Comment: It literally means what it says. STDIN normally wraps file descriptor 0. Your STDIN is not associated with fd 0, or any other file descriptor (system file handle).

Comment: @ikegami: The script is taking 1 argument and that's been passed as `$ARGV[0]`. Actually this `$ARGV[0]` is a file where I am doing read operation (But I don't have any STDIN to the script).

Comment: I think Net::OpenSSH is opening a file handle in the background. See this section 
"child process STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR is not a real system file handle"  on https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH

Comment: @vkk05 that error usually means you have [tied](https://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html) in some way `STDIN`, `STDOUT` or `STDERR`.

Comment: @salva But there is no as such `tie` I am using in the script.

Comment: @vkk05 some external module may be doing it or you may be opening a scalar reference as a flle. In any case, why don't you try the work arounds explained in the module FAQ? for instance, opening `/dev/null` and passing is as the default stdin file handler.

Comment: @salva : I have modified the script. Here is the updated [code](https://pastebin.com/jXyDR6TZ). But I am still facing the problem. The Error is not always `child process STDIN is not a real system..`. Sometimes it throws `IO::Pty` module doesn't exists even though it exists and I have mentioned module installation path using `$FindBin::Bin`. Correct me if I am doing anything wrong in the script.

Comment: @vvk05, you are still not showing us all the code. Probably some of the hidden parts is doing something unexpected with `stdin`.